# Virtual joystick moves to the right instantly when touching it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I touch the virtual joystick with the mouse, it instantly jumps to the right.

So I have to drag my mouse to the left on the screen, to drag the joystick back to the middle.

Here's a picture of it:

[image: joystick view]

My code looks this:

```
    public class VirtualJoystickController : Monobehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    private Vector3 inputVector = Vector3.zero; // the movementDirection
    private Image joystickBackgroundImage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("JoystickBackGroundImage").GetComponent<Image>(); // the joysticks background
    private Image joystickImage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<Image>(); // the joystick object to use

    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData e) // Click the joystick
    {
        OnDrag(e);
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData e) // leave the joystick
    {
        inputVector = Vector3.zero; // reset joystick
        joystickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }

    public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData e) // drag the joystick
    {
        Vector2 position;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform, e.position, e.pressEventCamera, out position)) // start dragging it
        {
            position.x = (position.x / joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
            position.y = (position.y / joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

            inputVector = new Vector3(position.x * 2 + 1, 0, position.y * 2 - 1);
            inputVector = inputVector.magnitude > 1 ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

            joystickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(
                inputVector.x * (joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3),
                inputVector.z * (joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Code

```
private Image joystickBackgroundImage;
private Image joystickImage;

public Vector3 InputDirection { set; get; }

private void Start()
{
    joystickBackgroundImage = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystickImage = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
    InputDirection = Vector3.zero;
}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData Ped)
{
    Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform, Ped.position, Ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {
        pos.x = (pos.x / joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

        float x = (joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.pivot.x == 1f) ? pos.x * 2 + 1 : pos.x * 2 - 1;
        float y = (joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.pivot.y == 1f) ? pos.y * 2 + 1 : pos.y * 2 - 1;

        InputDirection = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
        InputDirection = (InputDirection.magnitude > 1) ? InputDirection.normalized : InputDirection;

        joystickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(InputDirection.x * (joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3), InputDirection.z * (joystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y/3));
    }
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData Ped)
{
    OnDrag(Ped);
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData Ped)
{
    InputDirection = Vector3.zero;
    joystickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
}
```

u need to set **pivot point** same as **position** in **Ancor Presets** for joystick container